# Port 8080 required by Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition (Runtime) v2.8 at localhost is already in use

Tags: java, tomcat

```
i run a java application in STS on 8080 port of tomcat successfully.After then when i tried to start the server using below configuration in catalina.properties.
base.shutdown.port=-1
base.jmx.port=6968
bio.http.port=8078
bio.https.port=8442
```

i got above error.

In another attempt when i stopped my java app, i was able to start the server on 8078 port.
Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This one comes up pretty often. what I would do is..

1. open a terminal and run the following commands
2. sudo lsof -i :8080 (get PID of application)
3. kill -KILL ( PID of application)
4. Blow smoke off finger

Answer (score 0):

[change](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric53/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.9/getting-started/topic_g3d_xnj_qn.html) the port used by the Pivotal tc server...